# Cannot locate symbol "_ZNSt12__node_alloc13_M_deallocateEPvj" on X86 Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, crypto++

I am using latest NDK and Crypto++ 5.6.2. I compiled it for armeabi,armeabi-v7a, mips and x86 by following these instructions http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_(Command_Line)

I am currently using SHA256 from Crypto++.
I tested it on three devices (`arm` based android `2.3`,`5` and `5.1`) and it works fine. But when I try it on Genymotion (`x86`) and bundled android emulator(`x86`) it's not working.

`dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZNSt12__node_alloc13_M_deallocateEPvj"`

any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZNSt12__node_alloc13_M_deallocateEPvj"
> ```

Can you use `c++filt` to demangle/decode `_ZNSt12__node_alloc13_M_deallocateEPvj`? Also, does `nm -D` show the symbol present?

That almost looks like a STL node. If that's the case, then you're probably not including the C++ or STL library; or you're not calling `loadLibrary` in the right order. You need to include and preload `libstlport_shared.so`.

The wiki page even discusses a similar problem with `_ZNSt12__node_alloc11_M_allocateERj`:

> If you link to both libstlport_shared.so and libcryptopp.so, then you will have to preload libstlport_shared.so:
>
> ```
> shell@android:/ $ cd /data/local/tmp
> shell@android:/data/local/tmp $ ls
> TestData
> TestVectors
> cryptest.exe
> libcryptopp.so
> libstlport_shared.so
> shell@android:/data/local/tmp $
> shell@android:/data/local/tmp $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./; ./cryptest.exe v
> link_image[1936]:  5431 could not load needed library './libcryptopp.so' for './cryptest.exe'
> (reloc_library[1285]:  5431 cannot locate '_ZNSt12__node_alloc11_M_allocateERj'...)
> CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE
> shell@android:/data/local/tmp $
> shell@android:/data/local/tmp $ export LD_PRELOAD=`pwd`/libstlport_shared.so
> shell@android:/data/local/tmp $ echo $LD_PRELOAD                               
> /data/local/tmp/libstlport_shared.so
> shell@android:/data/local/tmp $
> shell@android:/data/local/tmp $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./; ./cryptest.exe v
> Using seed: 1375005963
>
> Testing Settings...
> ...
> ```

Comment: c++filt gives `std::__node_alloc::_M_deallocate(void*, unsigned int)` and `_ZNSt12__node_alloc11_M_allocateERj` is present. My load order is `stlport_shared`, `cryptopp` then my custom library. App works fine on device.